# Why do I keep receiving this error code? (how to fix it?)

Tags: python

When analyzing data sets, such as data for human heights or for human weights, a common step is to adjust the data. This adjustment can be done by normalizing to values between 0 and 1, or throwing away outliers.

For this program, read in a list of floats and adjust their values by dividing all values by the largest value. Output each value with two digits after the decimal point. Follow each number output by a space.

Ex: If the input is:

```
30.0 50.0 10.0 100.0 65.0
```

the output is:

```
0.30 0.50 0.10 1.00 0.65
```

What I have so far:

```
nums=[]
num_nums=int(input())

for i in range(num_nums):
    val=float(input())
    nums.append(val)

maximum=max(nums)
for i in range(num_nums):
    print(f'{(nums[i]/max):.2f}')
```

What I get back:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '30.0 '
```

Comment: Those don't look like `int` values. For your reference, `int` is short for ["Integer"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer).

Comment: what should I use instead?    Would it be     list

Comment: The first input which is assigned to `num_nums` should be an integer `5` because that's how many float values will be input following it.

Comment: 30.0 is a float, not an integer.

Comment: The easiest fix will be to replace `num_nums=int(input())` with `num_nums=int(float(input()))`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I simplified your code somewhat and put in some handy instructions to the user as well as some extra print statements in order to check on things. Comment out the extra print statements if you don't want them.

```
input_string=input("Please enter a list of values separated by a space, then press enter: ")
num_nums = input_string.split() 
print('list: ', num_nums)
for i in range(len(num_nums)):
    num_nums[i] = float(num_nums[i])
    
print('float conversion: ', num_nums)


print('largest entry: ', max(num_nums))
for i in range(len(num_nums)):
    math=(num_nums[i]/max(num_nums))
    result="{:.2f}".format(math)
    print(result, end=" ")
```